# In R, pacf() function not consistent with arima()$coef

Tags: r, time-series, arima, acf-pacf

Is my understanding off with what to expect from the following functions output:

```
arima(Y_t.TS.Residuals, order = c(2, 0, 0), include.mean=FALSE)$coef[2] 

pacf(Y_t.TS.Residuals, plot=F)[2]
```

Shouldn't these values be identical?

When I compute them I get -0.045 from the pacf amd -0.3376156 from the arima()$coef[2].

The data being inputted is obviously identical.

Thank you,

Christopher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arima()` uses full maximum likelihood estimation, while `pacf()` uses the Durbin-Levinson algorithm. So the objective functions are different, hence the estimates are different.

You should get the same result as `pacf()` if you use `ar()`.

```
pacf(lynx, plot=FALSE)[2]
#> 
#> Partial autocorrelations of series 'lynx', by lag
#> 
#>      2 
#> -0.588
ar(lynx, order=2)$ar[2]
#> [1] -0.5878918
```